# google calender - day before last friday of the month

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I want to create a recurring event in google calendar which occurs every thursday before the last friday of the month.

I tried this:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20180524
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1FR;BYSETPOS=-1
SUMMARY:My Rule
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

But it doesn't work.

I don't seem to understand how to simply substract one day from the result set. Meaning, I want to choose the last friday of a month an substract one day.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Getting the ics RFC5545 to do stuff is kinda like programming though, and we do answer questions like this at times.  There is no where else that I know of to ask these kind of questions.

Comment: I don't think one can subtract a day from the result set.  the BYSETPOS just helps one choose which element in the set.  So you'd have to have both the Thursday & Friday generated, while somehow excluding the thursday if it is the last day (ie doesnt have a Friday after it.)

Comment: @anmari I already tried to include both days but couldn't get it to work :(

Comment: I don't think it's possible.